# Function doesn't correctly perform unless it is called twice

Tags: javascript, html

Some background: I am using JavaScript to vertically center child divs that vary in height depending on conditions in their parent div. The centering function is as follows:

```
function autoCenter()
{var firstline = document.getElementById("ntext");
var secondline = document.getElementById("dtext");
var l1h = parseInt(getComputedStyle(firstline)["height"]);
var l2h = parseInt(getComputedStyle(secondline)["height"]);
var d1h = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("design"))["height"]);
var d2h = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("design2"))["height"]);
var totalh = l1h + l2h + d1h+ d2h;
document.getElementById("desdiv").style.top = (212-totalh)/2 + "px";
firstline.style.top = (212-totalh)/2  + d1h +"px";
secondline.style.top = (212-totalh)/2 + l1h + d1h + "px";
document.getElementById("desdiv2").style.top = (212-totalh)/2 + l1h + l2h + d1h+ "px";}
```

ntext, dtext, desdiv, and desdiv2 are the divs. The first 2 change based on the size of the text in them and the second 2 change based on the size of the image in them (ids design & design 2)

This function works perfectly when the only things changing are the text divs. I run into problems when I change the image divs. It appears that the first part of the function that involves getComputedStyle doesn't get the new height value for the image until the function is called a second time. After it's called the second time everything centers like it should. But ideally everything should work on the first call. What am I doing wrong here and how can I get the divs to center on the first call?

Edit: I'm not sure if this is relevant but autoCenter() is always called from within another function.

Comment: Do you have something against using semicolons?

Comment: Maybe this is because the images aren't fully loaded at the time the function is called for the first time? Try adding a setTimeout to check that.

Comment: @Lance Nope. Is it generally considered better practice to always put them in at the ends of lines that can have them? I'm still pretty new to this.

Comment: @Lance I don’t think missing semicolons are strange enough a style choice to comment on. JavaScript does let you leave them out, and it’s safe as long as you’re careful to still write them in the rare cases that the parser would get confused (such as lines beginning with `(`). And many other languages have chosen to omit semicolons, so certainly some people like the syntactical cleanliness that results.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane, it's not as safe as you might think. Better safe than sorry, always use semicolons.

Comment: @Ducky Better safe than sorry. Leaving out semicolons can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Rory O'Kane, just because a language let's you do something doesn't mean it is safe or a best practice. As a best practice, always use semicolons.

Comment: @Lance - It leads to unexpected behaviour only if you don't know the rules; the behaviour is 100% predictable. But yes, in this case Ducky did indicate being new, so presumably doesn't know the rules. I do recommend semicolons to newcomers, and use them myself, but I wouldn't go so far as to say "always" as a blanket rule for everybody.

Comment: @Marcel Gwerder The setTimeout() worked, so you were right about the loading. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely because your images aren't loaded fully at the time you call the center function.

Add an event listener to the images so that the center function fires when the images are loaded.

As for semicolons. Put them in, always. Look up semicolon insertion.

Comment: What would be the best way to add an event listener to the images? Would I use onload=  or something else?

Comment: Personally, I  use addEventListener, but it's really up to you and which specification you like. When creating the img element, add the listener. Then, whenever you change the src, the onload should fire when the new src loads. I've had to do this many times and it works.