# How to call a Javascript Function and make it perform twice properly?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-9

Good evening, I have a javascript function to set background color, etc when user onclick the table row. The function does not perform correctly unless it is called twice or when I press F12 for development tools, similar situation as [Function doesn't correctly perform unless it is called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114491/function-doesnt-correctly-perform-unless-it-is-called-twice).

I managed to handle it as below but the problem is that, when the user onclick the table row, it needs around 2-3 seconds for the background color to be change. How can I reduce the time for the function to perform twice?

> **JavaScript**

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
         setBackGroundColorOnIE (tableRowNumber) {
              //........
              //........
              setBackGroundColorOnIE (tableRowNumber)//I need the function to perform twice in one call
         }
    </SCRIPT>
```

I know it is a bad practice, but I'm really have no idea on how to fixed the compability issues in IE9. So, I came out with something like this. Need some hints and advices, thanks in advanced.

Comment: There is an infinite loop unless you have a condition or something to break out of it.

Comment: This will cause stackoverflow since it's a recursive call

Comment: infinite loop, ok thanks a lot for pointing out the problem...
I'll do something to break the loops, thks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add some condition to check if your function need to run again, like:

```
function setBackGroundColorOnIE (tableRowNumber) {   
   //check if your condition is met
   if( some_condition) {
       var timerId = setTimeout(function() {
        setBackGroundColorOnIE (tableRowNumber);
       }, 5000); //set to 5 seconds
   }
   else {
       clearTimeout ( timerId );
   }
}
//call the function
setBackGroundColorOnIE(some_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to include jquery ui which would allow you to change the color and then have a callback when the color change is completed. Here is a JS fiddle with jquery and jquery ui. http://jsfiddle.net/kqMs9/

```
$(function(){
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.background').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#000'
    }, 1500, function(){ alert('background-color changed!');});

});
```

});

Comment: ya, thanks for the concept...
the Jquery is not allowed in my program due to some issues, thks...